# C++ Text based rpg inventory

Tags: c++, inventory

Ok, right now I have thr bare bones of a text based rpg.

you know the usual:
health
monsters
location
gold
attack
etc

but, one thing i could never work out is how classes work + using multiple .cpp files to split the game up so it's easier to manage.

I guess my question is, how do I create an inventory for "Randomised weapons" ( as in psuedo-random) + does anyone have any explanation how to use multiple .cpp files together to hold seperate parts of the code.

keep in mind that i have read MULTIPLE descriptions and how-to's but most have either given me a headache or were just rubbis and explained nothing.

If you would like, i can copy and paste my code into paste-bin for you to look at, as i known it can always be improved and modified.

Comment: The paste-bin link might help. Multiple `cpp` files is pretty basic c++ project management.

Comment: What operating system and compiler?  And do you use an IDE?

Comment: @indiv - I don't see how that is relevant?

Comment: @Aesthete: Because when you break it up into multiple .cpp files, you're going to have to know how to link all the resulting object files maybe?

Comment: You seem to be asking two unrelated questions: 1) how to divide a code base into multiple source files, and 2) how to "create an inventory for randomised weapons" (WTHTM).

Comment: Consider asking these two questions individually. It's unlikely that you're looking for one person who best answers both these questions simultaneously.

Comment: pastebin.com/x2nZWVhH Here is the paste-bin with my program in it. :) hope this is helpful in answering my question

Answer (score 3):

I think your question is too broad.  But I'll offer a suggestion anyway.

Presumably, being an RPG, there are a number of items you can find.  Some are weapons, some are armour, some have other value, and some are just useless.  If I was approaching this, I might choose to have a class to represent them all and call it `Item`.  I might even derive types from this: `Weapon`, `Armour`, `Trinket`, ...

I would also register all my weapons in the program somehow.  Let's say I had a simple constructor...

```
Weapon::Weapon( const char *name, int cost, int minlevel, int damage, int speed );
```

Now, this weapon registry/repository would be whatever sort of container I felt sensible.  It could be just a C-style array, a `vector`, or it might be a `map` or something that allows name lookup.  It may even be a class you create yourself that can do other nice things.  So let's do that (and internally you might just use a `vector`).

When you start up, you'll want to register all your items.  Let's imagine that you keep separate lists in your registry for different item types.  So you might have an `Add` function for weapons and another for armour....

```
void Repository::Add( Weapon &weapon )
{
    weapons.push_back(weapon);
}
```

Your initialisation might go like this.

```
Repository repository;   // A global somewhere, maybe...

repository.Add( Weapon( "Plastic Spork", 1, 1, 1, 10 ) );
repository.Add( Weapon( "M. C. Hammer", 5, 5, 5, 15 ) );
repository.Add( Weapon( "Stroustrup", 1000, 100, 0x7fffffff, 1 ) );
// etc...
```

Now you have every weapon (and other item) available in your repository.  Choosing a bunch of random weapons is now quite easy.

```
Weapon Repository::RollWeapon( int minlevel )
{
    //...
}
```

That is, if I understood your question correctly.  Perhaps you are wanting to generate weapons with random stats.  There would be a number of ways to do this, but you might want to consider having a function on `Weapon` (or indeed `Item`) that randomizes/perturbs the stats on a registered item.

```
virtual void Item::RandomizeStats();
```

The weapon-version of this function would maybe just take the default `damage` value and alter it by +/- 20%.  In that case, it might as simple as this:

```
virtual void Weapon::RandomizeStats()
{
    int amount = damage / 5;
    damage += (rand() % (amount * 2 + 1)) - amount;
}
```

And you could even build that into your repository:

```
Weapon Repository::RollRandomizedWeapon( int minlevel )
{
    Weapon w = RollWeapon( minlevel );
    w.RandomizeStats();
    return w;
}
```

Anyway, hope something in this answer is useful to you.  There's a fair bit of conjecture on my part...

Comment: sorry for the late reply,  paddy that answer was perfect for the random weapons part of my question :) the other part was that i use codeblocks and win 7: 64 bit. i would use visual c++ but it doesnt want to workwith my program or any tutorial. for aome reaso . oh well,

Comment: When you say it "doesn't want to work", what do you mean?  Are you having namespace issues perhaps?  I've run across codeblocks stuff in the past, and vaguely remember it being namespaced up to the eyeballs.  Assuming that you're new to C++, you might be confused by namespaces.

Comment: alot of the includes dont work, and when i use some tutorials from the internet, tjey wont work. as in error galore. but onky from visual studi c++, c# works fine.